# MS Access 2003 Forms

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

Is it possible to link 2 forms to insert data into 1 table?  So, I have 1 form that a customer fills out and another form for the person who fulfills the request (this person enters comments, actual closed date, etc) but I don't want the customer seeing these fields...hence the reason for 2 forms.

Is it better just to separate the tables then join them with a query?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.  For the 1st form, just put in the fields you want the customer to see.  The second form can show all the fields for the staff member who fills in the request.